# How to query a Django queryset through a foreign key on another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following **models** in my project:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    ...

class File(models.Model):
    class StatusType(models.TextChoices):
        ACTIVE = "ACTIVE", _("ACTIVE")
        DELETED = "DELETED", _("DELETED")

    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=StatusType.choices,
        default=StatusType.ACTIVE,
    )
```

Basically, in one of my views, I want to a get a list of all the cases where the following conditions are met through the `File` model:

- `user` = `request.user`
- `status` = `"ACTIVE"`

How can I do this in a simple way? I can query for all the files first and then loop through them and add the cases to a list. Is that the best way to go about this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use a double underscore, eg `user__username='fred'` in the filter

Comment: See the [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) page in the Django docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach that would work the same as @anamul's answer

```
Case.objects.filter(
    file__user=request.user.id, 
    file__status=StatusType.ACTIVE,
)
```

You didn't specify the related name for the case FK from `File`, so `file__` here might need to be changed to `file_set__`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    active_file = File.objects.filter(status=StatusType.ACTIVE, user=request.user)

    cases = Case.objects.filter(file__in=active_file)

    context = {'case': cases}

    return render(request, 'test.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Or just `cases = Case.objects.filter(file__in=active_file)`

Comment: @bdbd  You use `in` then it expects value as list

Comment: `active_file` is a queryset which is 'list-like'